# In ASP.NET MVC, can I automatically model bind to a JObject from the POST body?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net, model-binding

I have a controller action that takes a JSON document as the body of a POST request. I'd love to automatically create a `JObject` from that, via model binding, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([FromBody] JObject data)
{
  // "data" is now a populated JObject object
}
```

But I get errors about not creating an abstract class. I tried to extend something from `JObject`, but it wouldn't do that either.

I know I can just read the body of the request and call `JObject.Parse` on it (I'm doing this, so it does work), but my idea from above seems so much more elegant.

Is this possible?

**Edit:** The actual error is:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class.
[MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class.]
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean&amp; canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal&amp; ctor, Boolean&amp; bNeedSecurityCheck)
[Stack trace continues...]
```

The request never gets into the controller action.

Based on my research `JObject` isn't abstract, but just to be sure, I did this:

```
public class Entry : JObject
```

Then

```
public ActionResult Index([FromBody] Entry data)
```

Didn't work. Same error.

Comment: Is your document's json of type JObject?

Comment: `JObject` is just a generic object for holding JSON of any type. Kind of like `XmlDocument` holds XML of any type. This is from the `JSON.Net` library.

Comment: Is `FromBody` something you have created?

Comment: No. https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: To me it seems that should work . what exactly is the error?

Comment: Updated question with error.

Comment: can you clarify whether you're using ASP.NET MVC, Web API, or ASP.NET Core MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might have been two problems. I changed two things, and it works now, but I'm not 100% sure which one fixed it.

Here are both things I changed --

First, I inherited from `ApiController` instead of just `Controller`.  I'm not sure if this had anything to do with it.

Second, one of the other answers pointed out that I needed to have the correct `Content-Type` header of `application/json`. Well, it wasn't. The `Content-Type` header was set to some wild value specific to the software we're integrating with.

So, in `Application_Start`, I added this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("[crazy ass content-type header value]"));
```

And then it worked.

I suspect it was the second thing that fixed it. Since the header didn't tell the model binder it was incoming JSON, the binder was trying to create a `JObject` object from scratch and assign properties via reflection which ran into problems with `JToken` being abstract. Once it knew it was dealing with JSON, it knew to just call `JObject.Parse` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should also put the structure of the JSON in your question. The full request would be better. Until then, try the following:

replace `[FromBody] JObject data` with `[FromBody] dynamic data` or `[FromBody] object data`

and see if it hits a breakpoint put on the first line of the action.

If it does, see what your dynamic actually is (type).

If it does not, maybe the POST request does not have `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: The last sentence in this answer helped me solve it. See my answer.

Comment: Glad to hear this :)

Answer (score 1):

I've written a ASP.NET Core ModelBinder for JToken which you can install - https://github.com/mcintyre321/AspNetCoreJTokenModelBinder

Bind to JToken, then use `.ToObject<T>()` in your controller

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that at some point when deserializing to type `JObject`, it calls to create a `JToken' and that is where the exception is thrown. Here is the exact exception:

> Cannot create an abstract class. Object type
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken